# HttpUrlConnection Post to Laravel - java.io.filenotfoundexception

Tags: php, android, laravel, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to post to a Laravel using HttpUrlConnection. But as the title suggest, it is throwing exception.

Kindly check my code and let me know, where i am wrong.

```
 public String HttpUrlPost()
    {
        BufferedWriter writer;
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        String data;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.104/laravel5/public/login");
            Log.d(TAG,"URL is : " + url.toString());

            data = URLEncoder.encode("username",HTTP.UTF_8) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("me",HTTP.UTF_8);
            data += "&"  + URLEncoder.encode("password",HTTP.UTF_8) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("admin",HTTP.UTF_8);
            Log.d(TAG,"data is : " + data);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, HTTP.UTF_8));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Laravel side is very simple. I just want to check if post returns anything.

```
Route::post('login',function(){

$users = array('username' => 'a', 'password'=>'d');
return $users;});
```

Please note that I am able to use Get method easily with laravel (it returns Json).

Comment: What kind of exception? In which catch block? Caused by which statement?

Comment: java.io.filenotfoundexception

Comment: Were not there three questions?

Comment: it was throwing error i started to read InputStream. Anyway. I found out after trying for past 3 days that the problem was from laravel side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php you could try updating the file to something like:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    private $openRoutes =
    [
        'public/login',
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach($this->openRoutes as $route)
        {
            if ($request->is($route))
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }
};
```

This allows you to explicitly bypass specific routes that you do not want verified without disabling csrf validation globally. I use it for my ajax calls.

Comment: thanks aethergy for the code snippet. but its not working for me.

Comment: ok. Its working. there was a problem with my file or understanding :) Anyhow, Is there a way to keep the csrf authentication for android app as well? casue i'll be using lot of crud operations on various tables from the app.